# Anonymous block to call oracle sql function that return list of values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem, I have a function and I need to call it through anonymous block, but I don't know how to do it...

Can someone help me?!

This is the code:

```
function x(a number, b date) return AABAAD600_PS.list
is
dichantim_tab AABAAD600_PS.LIST;
anti aabaa_table;
i number := 0;
begin
    dichantim_tab := AABAAD600_PS.LIST();

    for c1_rec in ( cursor)
        loop
            i := i + 1;
            dichantim_tab.extend;
            dichantim_tab(i).ID_ANTI := c1_rec.ID_ANTI;
            ...
            ...
            ...
        end loop;
    return dichantim_tab;
```

I tried this :

```
select AABAAD620_PS.x (a, sysdate) 
from dual;
```

and this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE (AABAAD620_PS.x (a, sysdate));
```

but nothing works...

Comment: Actually both statements should work. What do you mean by "nothing works"?

Comment: If you are making those calls in an anonymous block then you would need to select *into* something; but why do you want/need to use a PL/SQL block, and what do you want to do with the collection returned by the function?

Comment: You say "calling through an anonymous block", but your examples are sql statements - that is something very different. Please provide declaration of the "AABAAD600_PS.LIST" object and explain what output you are expecting and how you plan to invoke (anonymous block or sql statement)

Answer (score 0):

You said you have to call that function from an anonymous PL/SQL block, but there's no evidence you actually did that. Both `select` statements you posted work at SQL level.

Here's example which simulates the situation.

Function returns built-in collection datatype:

```
SQL> create or replace function x (a number)
  2    return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4    retval sys.odcinumberlist;
  5  begin
  6    select level
  7      bulk collect into retval
  8      from dual
  9      connect by level <= a;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

This is your first `select`:

```
SQL> select x(3) from dual;

X(3)
--------------------------------------------------------------
ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 2, 3)
```

This is your second `select`:

```
SQL> select * from table(x(3));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
           3
```

And this is anonymous PL/SQL block. If you want to make it work, you have to declare a local variable so that it could accept values returned by the function. I'm then just displaying its contents.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    result sys.odcinumberlist;
  3  begin
  4    result := x(3);
  5
  6    for i in result.first .. result.last loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(result(i));
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
1
2
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I guess that's what you were looking for. If not, what is it, then?